# JQuery .remove() doesn't work on dynamic added element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem removing element from page.
When I click on a button on a page it adds `div` like this:

```
<div class="holder-div" style="position: relative;display: inline-block;">              
            ...
            <i class="RemoveMeAndParent"></i>           
            </div>
```

And when I click on `RemoMeAndParent` I want to remove what I added:

```
$('body').on('click', '.RemoveMeAndParent', function () {
                $(this).closest('div').remove();
```

But this doesn't remove `holder-div` no error no nothing.
Just for a test I called `.empty()` and it work.
So why removing this div is not possible?

This is how I added it to the page:

```
var $this = $(this);
var newElement = $('<div class="holder-div" style="position: rel...');
newElement.prependTo($this);
```

Comment: The basics of your example work fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/omz3uo41/. Can you create a fiddle the reproduces your problem?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the element you are removing is dynamic, it only matters if the element you are attaching the event to is dynamic. (You happened to have catered for this by attaching the event to `body` anyway..)

Comment: I don't understand I tried on fiddle and it works fine in my code it doesn't :/

Answer (score -2):

put the remove function and wrap it in another function and recall that function when you've added the dynamic element.

The function is probably wrapped in a document ready which waits till the dom is is finished loading so it has all the elements. if you add an element after that javascript didn't register it or something. so if you would wrap that remove function in another function and call that after you've added the dynamic element it should work.

Comment: The `click` event is being registered on the `body` element and then subsequently filtered with the selector, which _will_ match dynamically added content.

Answer (score -2):

Please check this fiddle for answer:

http://jsfiddle.net/cq3vd0yx/6/

The problem is not that element can not be removed, but its rather that event binding dynamically is failing. For dynamic event binding using jQuery, use this syntax:

```
$(document).on( eventName, selector, function(){} );
```

Comment: What does the OP's `$('body').on('click', '.RemoveMeAndParent', function () {` look like to you?

Comment: Plz check fiddle, its document and not 'body'.

Comment: And here's your fiddle with body instead of document. Same result. see my comment in the question and the OP's responses and you'll see the code he posted works. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rajd01o9/